# Big Oh power difference?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

Can a function with higher power like $n^3$ become big oh for a lower power function let say $O(n^2)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To say that $f(n) = O(n^2)$ is the same as saying there exists a constant $C$ such that $f(n) \le Cn^2$ for large enough $n$.

However, $$\frac {n^3} {n^2} \to \infty \ \ \ \ \ {\text{as } n\to\infty}$$
so there cannot exist such a constant.

Comment: Just one more quick question can $f(x) = 2$ be $O(n)$ or $\Omega(n)$

Comment: A constant function is certainly $O(n)$ because it's less than $C_1n$ for all $n\ge 1$. However, it can't be $\Omega(n)$ because then it would have to be more than $C_2n$ for some constant $C_2$ for large enough $n$, which is absurd.